# Validation an Email in PHP?

Tags: php

```
     <?php
          if (isset($_POST["sendMessage"])) {
          $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
          $lastName = $_POST['last-name'];
          $email = $_POST['email'];
          $phone = $_POST['phone'];
          $message = $_POST['message'];
          $from= 'info@address.com';
          $to = 'some@gmail.com';
          $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';
          $txt= 'demo';
          $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
         "CC: somebodyelse@example.com";
        $body = "From: First-Name: $firstName\n Last-Name: $lastName\n                    

        E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Message: $message";
                        $errFirstName='';$errLastName='';$errEmail='';$errPhone='';$errMessage='';



// If there are no errors, send the email

        if (mail ($to, $subject,$txt,$headers)) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
        }
    }

?>
```

i am trying to make a mail validation but it will not work.Here some text which will give a success message or error message.but it show nothing . i can't  understand my fault. please help someone.

Comment: i didn't see any mail validation code here?

Comment: can you specify the results or errors if there are any?

Comment: Are you german? You should google the meaning of the word "will" in english. Beside that, try to be more constant with your variable names... `firstName` and `last-name` - thats bad practice. Also, may edit your question and remove your e-mail adress and replace it with some random stuff... don't think that its a good idea to post your e-mail adress on a public board. Also, what are you trying to achieve by ` $errFirstName='';$errLastName='';` and so..?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Think he means the `if-else` condition at the end - a validation if the message has been sent...

Comment: @Twinfriends thx a lot for your good suggestion.

Comment: Do you recive any error messages, or do you just see a white blank page?

Comment: @Farjana may you wan't to join the chatroom here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141332/validation-a-email-in-php so we can talk outside this comment section. I'll try to help you if you join, but we would have to write so many comments, think its better if we're in chatroom.

Comment: @Twinfriends i am here in chatroom

Answer (score 1):

Try this code on your live server

```
    $firstName = "sunny";
    $lastName = "khatri";
    $email = '******@gmail.com';
    $phone = '********';
    $message ='Hello this is test';
    $from= '*****@gmail.com';
    $to = '***@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';
    $txt= 'demo';
    $headers = "From: ******@*****.com" . "\r\n" .
    "CC: ********@live.in";
    $body = "From: First-Name: $firstName\n Last-Name: $lastName\n                    

    E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Message: $message";
                $errFirstName='';$errLastName='';$errEmail='';$errPhone='';$errMessage='';

    // If there are no errors, send the email

    if (mail ($to, $subject,$txt,$headers)) {
          $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
         $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
    echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use default function from PHP manual:

```
<?php
    $email_a = 'joe@example.com';
    $email_b = 'bogus';

    if (filter_var($email_a, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "This ($email_a) email address is considered valid.\n";
    }
    if (filter_var($email_b, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "This ($email_b) email address is considered valid.\n";
    } else {
   echo "This ($email_b) email address is considered invalid.\n";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First You Have To Check Email Is Valid Using This Php Function

```
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
}
```

Then If Its Not Valid Give A Error
Else

```
if (mail ($to, $subject,$txt,$headers)) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
        }
```

try it..